# define global variable in autobahn with python

Tags: python, web-services, global-variables, autobahn

I want to create a chat application with python autobahn that send received messages to all clients.So firstly I must define a global variable like a dictionary and put some info on it(client : messages have not been downloaded).
I need define a global variable but I cant do it
I define that dictionary like this code but it is unique for each client

```
class MyProtocol(WebSocketServerProtocol):
    clients_msgs = {}  # this must be global for all clients
    .
    .
    .
```

so how should i define my variable ?

Answer (score 0):

> You must use ClassName.attributeName in python for a global variable between all instance of class.

```
>>> class Test(object):
...     i = 3
...
>>> Test.i
3
>>> t = Test()
>>> t.i     # static variable accessed via instance
3
>>> t.i = 5 # but if we assign to the instance ...
>>> Test.i  # we have not changed the static variable
3
>>> t.i     # we have overwritten Test.i on t by creating a new attribute t.i
5
>>> Test.i = 6 # to change the static variable we do it by assigning to the class
>>> t.i
5
>>> Test.i
6
>>> u = Test()
>>> u.i
6
```